# Managing jBASE triggers

Tags: multivalue, multivalue-database, jbase

I have reviewed the [jBASE documentation](https://docs.zumasys.com/jbase/triggers) on triggers but I have some additional questions on managing them.

1. Does a trigger use up a license seat? If so, continuously, or only upon action?
2. Does a trigger continue running in the background like a phantom process?
3. How do we manage them i.e. pause, stop, restart a trigger?
4. Do I need to restart the trigger after a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger is an extension of the file I/O and the process doing the I/O would be using a jBASE license at the time of the I/O, but no additional license is needed for the trigger itself.

The trigger again is an extension of file I/O, so no it is not background or phantom process, but is simply a process that runs at the trigger point

Triggers are not started or stop, only defined.  If a trigger is defined for a trigger point, during file I/O that trigger will run.

Triggers are integral to the file I/O and therefore do not need to be "restarted"